# Java file path in web project

Tags: java, file

I need to access the resource files in my web project from a class. The problem is that the paths of my development environment are different from the ones when the project is deployed.

For example, if I want to access some css files while developing I can do like this:

```
File file = new File("src/main/webapp/resources/styles/some.css/");
```

But this may not work once it's deployed because there's no `src` or `main` directories in the target folder. How could I access the files consistently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be storing your CSS file in the classpath for some unobvious reason. The folder name `src` is typical as default name of Eclipse's project source folder. And that it apparently magically works as being a relative path in the `File` constructor (bad, bad), only confirms that you're running this in the IDE context.

This is indeed not portable.

You should not be using `File`'s constructor. If the resource is in the classpath, you need to get it as resource from the classpath.

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/webapp/resources/styles/some.css");
// ...
```

Assuming that the current class is running in the same context, this will work regardless of the runtime environment.

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

---

**Update**: ah, the functional requirement is now more clear.

> Actually I want to get lastModified from the file. Is it possible with InputStream? –

Use `getResource()` instead to obtain it as an `URL`. Then you can open the connection on it and request for the `lastModified`.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/main/webapp/resources/styles/some.css");
long lastModified = url.openConnection().getLastModified();
// ...
```

Comment: Actually I want to get `lastModified` from the file. Is it possible with `InputStream`?

Comment: No, but it's possible with `URL`.

Comment: That's great answer, but I have one more problem. I need to use `static` function to call it from JSTL. But `getClass` function can not be called inside static function. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Use the classloader of the current thread's context. `URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path);`.

Answer (score 5):

If what you're looking to do is open a file that's within the browser-visible part of the application, I'd suggest using [ServletContext.getRealPath(...)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Thus:

```
File f = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("relative/path/to/your/file"));
```

Note: if you're not within a servlet, you may have to jump through some additional hoops to get the `ServletContext`, but it should always be available to you in a web environment.  This solution also allows you to put the .css file where the user's *browser* can see it, whereas putting it under `/WEB-INF/` would *hide* the file from the user.

Comment: @lan if i am in other class(module class) except servlet how can i get access of my folder which is in my classpath of project...

Comment: I think it would be better if you asked that as a new question, rather than trying to jump off from here.  That will give you a chance to describe what you're trying to do better, and give others a chance to give you more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Put your external resources in a sub-directory of your project's `WEB-INF` folder. E.g., put your css resources in `WEB-INF/styles` and you should be able to access them as:

new File("styles/some.css");

Unless you're not using a standard WAR for deployment, in which case, you should explain your setup.

Comment: Putting external resources in a sub-directory of `WEB-INF` folder is the best practice? @Robin said, "Typically resource files are placed in your war along with your class files". I'm confused

Comment: And it seems I cannot access the file like `new File("styles/some.css");` while developing. :(

Answer (score 1):

Typically resource files are placed in your war along with your class files.  Thus they will be on the classpath and can be looked up via

```
getClass.getResource("/resources/styles/some.css")
```

or by opening a File as @ig0774 mentioned.

If the resource is in a directory that is not deployed in the WAR (say you need to change it without redeploying), then you can use a VM arg to define the path to your resource.

```
-Dresource.dir=/src/main/webapp/resources
```

and do a lookup via that variable to load it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java web project, the standard directory like:

```
{WEB-ROOT} / 
           /WEB-INF/
           /WEB-INF/lib/
           /WEB-INF/classes
```

So, if you can get the class files path in file system dynamic, 
you can get the resources file path.

you can get the path ( /WEB-INF/classes/ ) by:

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

so, then the next ...

Comment: the above code gives the complete path to the Class File, but not to the classes folder.

Comment: You know the path to the Class File, and other side, you can know the package of the Class, so, you can get what you want.